# C++: Class constructor: variable_name'' must be initialized

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to make a class in c++ called `MyClass`. However I got an error message in my cpp file of `MyClass`. More specific in the constructor of the class. I have made a seperate class `OtherClass`, but that code works. `OtherClass` is used as a datatype in `MyClass` for certain parameters.

Here is the h code of `MyClass`:

```
// MyClass.h

#ifndef "MyClass_h"
#define "MyClass_h"

#include 'OhterClass.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class MyClass {

public:
    MyClass (vector<OtherClass>, vector<string>, OtherClass);
       // more code

private:
    vector<OtherClass> variable_A;
    vector<string> variable_B;
    OtherClass variable_C;

};
```

This is the constructor in MyClass.cpp, where I get the error message:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass(vector<OtherClass> _variable_A, vector<string> _variable_B, OtherClass _variable_C){
    variable_A = _variable_A;
    variable_B = _variable_B;
    variable_C = _variable_C;
}
```

> Field 'variable_C' must be initialized

Comment: Post all the code.

Comment: This is blatantly obviously not your real code. -1

Comment: @T.C., Yeah of course I did it because it would be easier to read and understand for you guys :)

Comment: You mean "riddled with extra errors so that people can't tell what's what"?

Answer (score 1):

`OtherClass` probably does not have defined default constructor. While constructing `MyClass`, the compiler must know how to construct all of its members, including `variable_C`. Use constructor initializer list for that (or at least for that)

```
MyClass::MyClass(vector<OtherClass> _variable_A, vector<string> _variable_B, OtherClass _variable_C)
    : variable_C(_variable_C)
{
    variable_A = _variable_A;
    variable_B = _variable_B;
//    variable_C = _variable_C;
}
```

BTW: You should be passing those arguments as references (ideally as `const&`).

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that `OtherClass` does not have a **default constructor**.  Initialization of `MyClass`'s fields happens before the body of the `MyClass` constructor is entered.  In your example, `MyClass` needs to be able to **default-construct** each of its fields before it can then assign any new values to them.  You are doing assignment, not initialization, in the constructor body.

Performing separate construction and assignment is not ideal.  You really should be using the constructor's [**member initialization list**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) instead.

Also, you should be passing in the input values (especially the `std::vector` objects) by const reference instead of by value to avoid allocating unnecessary temporaries.

Try this instead:

```
#ifndef MyClass_h
#define MyClass_h

#include "OtherClass.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MyClass {

public:
    MyClass (const vector<OtherClass> &, const vector<string> &, const OtherClass &);
       // more code

private:
    vector<OtherClass> variable_A;
    vector<string> variable_B;
    OtherClass variable_C;

};

#endif
```

```
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass(const vector<OtherClass> &_variable_A, const vector<string> &_variable_B, const OtherClass &_variable_C)
    : variable_A(_variable_A), variable_B(_variable_B), variable_C(_variable_C)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, you are not initializing.

It is just assignment, the initialization process occurs before the assignment operations in constructor.

Use initializer list instead.

In "effective C++" Scott clearly says about this.. please refer it. (some where in (Chapter 1 item4)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Otherclass is having parameterized constructor. Use initialisation list to initialise the Otherclass member variables.

Comment: can you explain your code more with example and code?